# App UWP conecta SQL Server 2012 sem WebService?

Tags: sql, .net, uwp, iot

Preciso desenvolver uma aplicação UWP em C#/XAML para uso na indústria para coleta de dados via celular Lumia 640 XL com Windows 10 Mobile. Toda a persistência (CRUD) será em SQL Server 2012 na rede corporativa interna. A app será extendida depois a outros devices (Tables + PC e até IoT). Ou seja, tudo será baseada em Windows 10.

Agora com o .Net Standard 2.0 dando suporte a System.Data, gostaria de saber se alguém já testou com sucesso esta conexão + CRUD diretamente no SQL Server 2012 externo do device sem o uso de WebServices.

Se sim, qual foi o veredito final?

Answer (score 0):

Se o dispositivo conectar na mesma que o BD rede sim. Caso contrário, precisará de um serviço (WCF, REST API etc) para realizar as transações no BD.